# Why are the after effects of elasticity maximum for glass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, elasticity, glass

> After effects of elasticity are maximum for
> A) Glass.
> B) Quartz
> C) Rubber.
> D) Metal

The correct answer given is glass. The vague explanation provided is that in the case of metal, the metallic bonds' sliding planes slide. In rubber, PVC, polythene, etc., covalent bonds rearrange. In quartz, repeating units of SiO2, and in glass, SiO4 and Na+, K+. Glass is a supercooled liquid.

Comment: A horribly worded question, with a variety of possible answers based on what is really meant by 'after effects'...

Comment: Agreed—"after effects" is ambiguous. This is just another very poorly constructed exam question. It's unfortunate that a million candidates take this exam every year.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.